# Workers status offline with no error

Tags: python, redis, rabbitmq, celery, celery-task

**Setup:** CentOS 7, Celery 4.1, RabbitMQ (broker), Redis (backend).

We have ~15 workers in 3 machines, each with concurrency 1-5.

We recently upgraded from 3.1 and Worker become offline randomly with no exception/error. In workers log it seems like it's finished tasks successfully.

Machines are monitored and this is not overload issue (cpu/memory are ok).
Any idea what could it be? what cause the workers randomly stop working? any suggestion how to debug?

BTW: we see the offline workers via flower.

Thanks

Comment: What are the logs of the celery process?

Comment: As I said, each one of the offline workers (not all of them are going down) logs looks ok, doesn't see any clue..